# Connection to industrial automation software (OPC?!)

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I´m searching for a way to connect ROS to standard industrial automation software like Freelance, WinCC/PCS7, Wonderware etc.
The obvious approach would be to use OPC (UA) but I can´t find a lot of info to this here in the wiki. I heard that there are some projects using OPC but I just don´t find any information.
Did anybody use OPC with ROS or has some info about it? Maybe there are some easier solutions?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/111841/connection-to-industrial-automation-software-(opc?!)/) by [Joe123456](https://answers.ros.org/users/10081/joe123456/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2013-12-18

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am aware of one effort to integrate ROS and OPC UA.  This was done by Fraunhofer IPA, but as far as I know this was not open sourced.

I have looked into doing this in the past.  There are several open source OPC clients (ex: http://www.openopcua.org/ ).  Creating a bridge between ROS utilizing these clients should be relatively straight forward for specific cases.

The more general case of creating a generic ROS bridge to OPC is a little more difficult, but one that I have interest in.  Should you decide to go down this road, please let me know.

---

Originally posted by [sedwards](https://answers.ros.org/users/78/sedwards/) with karma: 1601 on 2013-12-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3